# Android-Tools Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, sdk, compilation, version, gradle

I am currently trying to get the new build system for android (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/using-the-new-build-system) to work. Therefore I created a `build.gradle` file with the following contents:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    target='android-15'    

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 15
        minSdkVersion 8
        versionCode 10
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest {
                srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
    compile project(':ActionBarSherlock')
    compile fileTree(dir: './libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

I've done this based on the docs, so I expect it to work; however, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: The default configuration has an indirect dependency on Android
>   API level 14, but minSdkVersion for variant 'Debug' is API level 8

When removing the explicit dependency on android 4.0.1.2, the error vanishes but I am left with compile errors because Android files themselves cannot be resolved. As an example, `Activity` or `View` as classes cannot be found. Supposedly, I could downgrade to an older version of Android to match the `minSdkVersion`, but I want to compile against sdk `15` with a minimum of `8`.

The plugin itself is declared in a root build.gradle with version 0.3.

Has anyone of you got an idea how to resolve that error?

Thanks,
Matthias

Answer (score 4):

Hm somehow I got this to work using the support API instead of whole Android as dependency ... at least it works now ...

Comment: By the way, the `com.google.android:android` dependency is automatically added to your dependency list and interfered from the android versions you selected.

Comment: yes, no need to add the dependency on com.google.android:android. This is what android.compileSdkVersion is for (which btw replaces android.target so you can remove that line)