# Android Gradle Build without local SDK

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm trying to build an android project using gradle but my build environment won't have the android sdk installed locally. I see that Maven has a com.google.android:android artifact and I was hoping I could just use that. I've got the project compiling locally with the sdk installed but when I remove my local.properties file and try to rely on just the artifact I get an error saying that SDK Location was not found. My gradle file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "15.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
                srcDir 'src/generated/java'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
    compile project(':jll')
}
```

Any ideas? The only other mention I've found of doing this was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184253/android-tools-gradle-plugin) but there wasn't enough context for me to get mine to work from it, if this is even possible.